# Using Bower with Play

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, bower

This is what my file structure looks like in Play:

```
- public
  - bower_components
  - images
  - stylesheets
```

This is my `<head>`:

```
<head>
    <title>@title</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href='@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.at("bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")'>
    <script src='@routes.Assets.at("bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")'></script>
    <script src='@routes.Assets.at("bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")'></script>
</head>
```

The routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

GET     /public                     controllers.Application.public

GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

It works on development I am getting 200s. When I deploy to Heroku, I get 404s for all bower components except for the stylesheets and images directories.

I'm under the assumption that it may be because Play is not able to recognize the bower components directory. Does anyone know how to add a new directory for play to build from for the assets?

Comment: What is your mapping(s) for `Assets.at` in your `conf/routes` file?

Comment: How do you try to access the other files in your code? (not css and images)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using bower with play, be mindful that the assets that you will use are stored within the `/dist` folder. Now, you may not think this is a big deal, but if you check the default `.gitignore` file, you'll discover that on one single line it has these four characters:

```
dist
```

That is enough to ignore all `dist`s within your application. Just delete the line, run git status, and you'll discover you'll have some new files to add to your repo.

Commit and push to Heroku. You should be good to go by now.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to run bower on the server upon deployment, rather than version controlling the `dist` folder?

Comment: but then again `command bower not found`. Setting the version in the dist may help to keep at a single version if you just need some core functionality, but if you're moving with fontend technology, I agree, `dist` should be taken out of the repo, running and installing bower onto the server would be more productive and less of a headache.

Comment: I've never run Play on Heroku, so take this with a grain of salt, but my experience deploying Django to Heroku was that the default buildpacks didn't usually contain runtimes for other languages. You may have to modify your buildpack to have node and npm. But assuming you're not doing any backend Scala magic in your frontend assets, it's often better anyway to deploy those to a static file host anyhow.